# Installing BES Express with hosted exchange

Tags: exchange, blackberry, bes

Our company uses a Hosted Exchange which apparently does not have BES support there.

I tried to install the BES Express 5 but can't seem to go pass the MAPI Settings section. Following is the error: "The setup application could not contact the Microsoft Exchange Server to check the name of the mailbox"

Can anyone help? Or is it actually impossible to have Exchange and BES installed on different network?

Comment: Why neg? Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error's pretty self explanatory - your BES server can't contact your Exchange server.  Might be a misconfiguration on the BES server, a firewall rule blocking the communication, a missing route in your network... really, the possible causes are nearly endless, and you haven't given nearly enough information for anyone to do more than take shots in the dark.

Having said that, one of my previous jobs used BES and hosted Exchange, both of which I set  up, so it's certainly possible to run a setup like the one you're describing, with BES on a different network from Exchange.

Comment: Good to hear that it is possible. I actually followed the instructions here, but skipped all steps that requires Exchange because I have no control of that: http://www.commodore.ca/windows/exchange/blackberry/how-to-install-bes-express-exchange-2010-single-server.html

Comment: My problem is I am completely new on this thing and all examples I found on net has always been installing BESX with Exchange on same network.

Comment: @bong  Well, just because you have hosted Exchange doesn't mean you can skip all the Exchange steps.  You still need those steps performed to get BES and Exchange communicating.  If you have access to the Exchange server hosting your email, do those steps yourself, if not, you'll have to get your host to perform them for you.

Comment: One of the step requires is to "add permission to BESAdmin via Exchange management shell console". If they don't give me access to this, is that means what am trying to do is impossible? How did you do it in the past? Thanks

Comment: @bong Well, if they don't give you access to EMC, you tell **them** to perform `[the following steps]` and tell you when they're done.  As to how I did it in the past, I worked with hosts who gave me access to the Exchange environment they hosted for us.  You can't connect remotely to your Exchange instance with EMC or EMS?

Comment: Yes, I spoke to them and they don't give EMC access to people. Although, they actually have BES installed. Can I assume that since they have BES installed they would already created user "BESAdmin" with all permissions, make the registry entry, install MAPI, etc - and only thing left is adding permission for "BESAdmin" to my domain? and if that's done meaning only issue would be firewall?

Comment: Ah, btw the only reason I cannot use their BES is because they have limited features - and one of them that they don't support is the want I need, ie. pushing application to all Blackberry devices for compliance purposes. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Thanks - just in contact with our hosted exchange that I cannot install BESX since it requires them to open port 135, and grant special permission to BESAdmin user - which they cannot do. Only option I have now is move our Exchange or host ourselves.

Comment: @bong Yeah, I'd definitely move hosts.  RIM is circling the drain and all, but the restrictions your hosts are laying out are still ridiculous.  Time to find a host that knows what the hell they're doing.